# Get array of unique elements from arrays of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js, unique, union

i have arrays like the following ones:

```
files = [
       {name: 'Lorem', other: true},
       {name: 'Foo', other: true},
       {name: 'Bar', other: true}
      ];


files = [
       {name: 'Lorem', other: true},
       {name: 'Xxxxx', other: true}
      ];


files = [
       {name: 'Lorem', other: true},
       {name: 'Foo', other: true},
       {name: 'Epic', other: true},
       {name: 'Xxxxx', other: true}
      ];
```

I'm trying to get a merged array with unique elements with Underscore, but it doesn't work. Here is my code:

```
function getAllFiles(alldocs) {
  var all = [];

  _.each(alldocs, function(element) {
    all = _.union(all, element.files);
  });

  return all;
}
```

But i get an array with duplicate items.

Comment: see https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/issues/2311

Comment: You could probably use http://underscorejs.org/#uniq also with `union`

Comment: The solutions given below all check just for the 'name' property, but it's possibly you want to distinct over both 'name' and 'other' properties. Loop over the array and check both. If it's just the single value you want to check, you could do it with a map and reduce one-liner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using underscore you can do it like this:

```
files1 = [
       {name: 'Lorem', other: true},
       {name: 'Foo', other: true},
       {name: 'Bar', other: true}
      ];


files2 = [
       {name: 'Lorem', other: true},
       {name: 'Xxxxx', other: true}
      ];


files3 = [
       {name: 'Lorem', other: true},
       {name: 'Foo', other: true},
       {name: 'Epic', other: true},
       {name: 'Xxxxx', other: true}
      ];
//append all  json
all = _.union(files1,files2, files3);
//get unique by define function which returns name (deciding factor for unique)
all = _.uniq(all, function(d){return d.name});
console.log(all);//prints the unique elements
```

working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/9t2163c3/)

Answer (score 1):

A solution in plain Javascrift a temporary object and [`Array#forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```js
var files1 = [{ name: 'Lorem', other: true }, { name: 'Foo', other: true }, { name: 'Bar', other: true }],
    files2 = [{ name: 'Lorem', other: true }, { name: 'Xxxxx', other: true }],
    result = function (array) {
        var o = {}, r = [];
        array.forEach(function (a) {
            if (!(a.name in o)) {
                o[a.name] = a;
                r.push(o[a.name]);
            }
        });
        return r;
    }(files1.concat(files2));

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply [`uniq`](http://underscorejs.org/#union) method after `union` call.

The problem is that `uniq` by default uses `===` operator to test array element equality. So if you have array of objects, each object will be compared by **reference**, not value, which is obviously undesired behaviour. This problem can be solved by supplying `uniq` with extra parameter - callback function (`iteratee`) which will convert array element to simply comparable value. In your case you can use `JSON.stringify` method which returns string representation of an object.

```
function getAllFiles(alldocs) {
    var union = _.union.apply(null, alldocs.map(function(v) {
        return v.files;
    }));
    return _.uniq(union, function(v) {
        return JSON.stringify(v);
    });
}
var alldocs = [
    {files: [
       {name: 'Lorem', other: true},
       {name: 'Foo', other: true},
       {name: 'Bar', other: true}
    ]},
    {files: [
       {name: 'Lorem', other: true},
       {name: 'Xxxxx', other: true}
    ]},
    {files: [
       {name: 'Lorem', other: true},
       {name: 'Foo', other: true},
       {name: 'Epic', other: true},
       {name: 'Xxxxx', other: true}
    ]}
];
var result = getAllFiles(alldocs);
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qwaqprm9/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Using lodash, you can use `_.uniqBy`

```
result = _.uniqBy(result, function (e) {
  return e.name;
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mw230kea/1/

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are using an arrays of objects and **underscore doesn't know which object attribute to use when comparing items**(for example name,other),
here is a clean solution:

```
   files =  _.chain(files).indexBy("name").values();
```